# ajax login logout calls from same div don't fire until page refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication, session-cookies, logout

I am firing an ajax call for logging in a user to the website. The div "sitelogin" contains the login form parts. After successful ajax authentication the div "sitelogin" removes the login form parts and fills in the ajax html response. The response consists of a logout button and a div with "Welcome user".

Now the logout button is attached to another ajax call for destroying the session and bring back the login parts into the "sitelogin" div. But it does not fire until I refresh the page. Please tell me why does the logout ajax call does not fire if I try to logout with the "logout" button immediately after the login ajax call fills in the "sitelogin" div with the logout response. Both the ajax calls are in the page header.

I've posted more info here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627573/php-ajax-login-and-logout-not-working-together-and-with-nobody-logged-onto-the-s

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to the issue. Jquery has a way of handling elements which enter the dom at a later time. They grab the parent element and then delegate  the event to the actual triggering element whenever it is created.

I used the below.

```
    $('#parent div').on('click','#event triggering element',function(){
        $.ajax({
                //ajax function
            }
        });
        return false
    });
```

This solved my headache. Hopefully it will help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using jQuery Ajax.

Put your logout ajax call on that page from where your logout button and welcome user div comes.

So when your logout code comes in response, logout ajax call will be initialized, and you can call it without page refresh.

Comment: Yes, jquery ajax. Thanks for this suggestion. So if I understand correctly you are suggesting to add the javascript code in the response file itself so that it also loads up with the reeponse. Correct?
Will inserting javascript into the DOM like that works or we need to add something else. I'm happy if that works. By the way I'll remove the bind. That seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you bind the onclick event, when the element not exist yet. When the ajax response is put into the div, the bind is, of course, not triggered again.

You should print this javascript code only then, when the user has logged in - even for security reasons! You can print that javascript code directly with php and it will be executed when it is put into the div.

Comment: Ohh ok..you are right. So in case i do not bind but only use the click function should it work. Also as @number50 said I should keep the javascript in the login response thereby loading it with the response.

Can you just load the plain javascript through such a response. I was reading somewhere that the you have to use the eval() function. Is that true or simply passing the javascript code inside script tags will work.

Comment: You can make a <script type="text/javascript"> block in you ajax response - it is executed, if you put this response anywhere into an div or another element. You just have to put the <script> tag before and after it to show the browser that it is a javascript.